# Disadvantages of using multiple <style> and <script> tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

A little bit of context: I'm trying to make a simple site constructor. It's blocks are php files. When a user makes a request, I assemble a page from these blocks. These blocks should be independent of each other, so I put styles in style tag in this file and scripts in a script tag. Technically, it works.

The question is: is it right doing this? I mean, after build page looks like

```
<div class="block1">
<!-- some html here -->
</div>
<style>
/*some css for .block1 here*/
</style>
<script>
//some javscriot for block1
</script>

<div class="block2">
<!-- some html here -->
</div>
<style>
/*some css for .block2 here*/
</style>
<script>
//some javscriot for block2
</script>
```

Will the behavior of such code be somehow different from the traditional connection of all css/javascript that are in one file?

Comment: i'll don't think it's a problem

Comment: `<style>` tag within the body is invalid HTML that will not pass a W3C Markup check. The only alternative is the `scoped attribute` which however is onyl support by FF. In everyother case, it is invalid HTML and as such should be avoided.

Comment: Technically, it's invalid. In practice it's widely used and supported by browsers. But still you should attempt to avoid it. If you want to use style tags, put them in the `<head>` section. `Will the behavior of such code be somehow different`...unlikely, unless you somehow make a mistake. You _might_ get slightly better load times because the browser doesn't have to request separate CSS and JS files, but that can usually be mitigated by caching, using CDNs etc.